# Recommendation about a laptop

Tags: laptop

Today my laptop (HP pavillion g6-2209sl equipped with: i3-2370M @2.40GHz, RAM: 4 GB, SSD: 512 GB, AMD Radeon HD 7670M 2GB) has shown some problems, so I need to buy a new one tomorrow.

I'd like to buy a 15.6" laptop; I'll use it for my job, so to work with an IDE: like PyCharm, Visual Studio, Eclipse, ....
Moreover, while working with an IDE, I usually open many Google Chrome tabs simultaneously and, at the same time, I often also use programs like: MS Word, MS Teams and a Git Client (Gitkraken).

I don't use graphic/CAD programs like Photoshop or Autocad, but I want a laptop with a dedicated Graphic Card, in case, in future, I'll need to use (sometimes) any graphic programs.

The laptop I want to buy could have only 8 GB RAM, but, in this case, it must be expandable to 16 GB.
The budget is 800-850€.

In a shop in my city there's an HP 15-DW1080NL on sale, for a price of 699€ (instead of 799€).

It has:

- Intel i5-10210U @1.6 GHz (@4.2 GHz with Turbo Boost: 4.20 GHz), L3 cache: 6MB
- RAM 12 GB (I think not expandable)
- Graphic Card: Geforce MX130 2GB
- SSD M2 512 GB

My doubts are about:

- processor: it's not an i7, and it hasn't a very high frequency, but I hope, anyway, it will be sufficient for me (until now, I could say that my i3 has been sufficient)
- RAM: I would have preferred 8GB expandable to 16 GB, instead of 12 GB not expandable.
  Even if I'm not completely sure that RAM of HP 15-DW1080NL is really not expandable (do you know?)

So, finally, I'd like to have an opinion from you about HP 15-DW1080NL and about some doubts described above.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to know the power rating of your CPU when selecting laptops. There are many metrics to measure this but I like passmark. Particularly the **single-core rating** written in the smallest font, not that big orange multi-core score. Most programs can't use multiple cores to their full extent.

So google the name of your processor **10210U** and then type **passmark**, click the first result and now you know a lot more and can compare apples to apples.

https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core+i5-10210U+%40+1.60GHz&id=3542

- Multicore rating = 6548
- Single Thread Rating = 2278
- In comparison your i3-2370M has a single core rating of 1055 and a multicore rating of 1307, so be prepared for a 2x speed increase

Most computers these days have a CPU single core of 2500-3000 and multicore rating of 8000+. Indecent ones are below 2500 and a multicore rating of 4000 or below. Think of it like horsepower. Though you don't have an i7, it is a clever scheme to make you spend a lot more money for a bit more speed. It is faster though, no doubt, but a bad value.

Better yet punch in the CPU anf GPU of other laptops you see online or at your local shop.

https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=GeForce+MX130&id=3890

- Your HP's NVIDIA® GeForce® MX130 has a score of 1928 which is horrendous
- However your future workload is unknown so it might be suitable. An average GPU is 10000 and slightly less than 10000 if it is a laptop
- In comparison your current AMD Radeon 7670M has a score of 454, so be prepared for a 4x boost

It is clear that most of The HP laptop budget is going into that 512 GB m.2 SSD.

Try to look for another laptop with as high as possible CPU and GPU passmark scores in your price range. Or increase your price range, or be prepared to use this laptop with a shorter useful life span. I think your HP laptop you proposed will be good for 3-7 years as long as the GPU is not used. If you do plan on using that GPU then it is good for 1-3 years. These numbers are rough estimates since I do not know how demanding your workload is.

Try going for a

1. **Dell XPS 15** comes with Intel i7-10750H (Multicore = 12618 Single-core = 2745) and NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 Ti (Score = 7529), but pay more to upgrade ram to 16 GB
2. **HP Envy 14** comes with a Intel i5-1135G7 (Multicore = 9885 Single-core = 2740), but pay more to upgrade the ram to 16GB and pay more to upgrade to a NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 Graphics card (Score = 7725)

They are much better value in terms of what you are getting. As for laptop pricing of the 2 models suggested, it is decent in the USA and Canadian market, but I hope there are no markups in the UK and European markets

They all come with the speedy fast 256 GB m.2 drive, but you can later buy a bigger one in the future for cheap and stick it in as neccessary. Unfortunately you cannot do the same for the CPU and GPU so they are the main priority, don't worry about m.2 drive space that much.

Upgrading to 16 GB of ram is really helpful if you have 30-100 Google chrome tabs open, 16 GB is standard nowadays and 8 GB was the standard 5-10 years ago. 32 GB is becoming the future standard, but still 2-5 years till that happens. You can go with with 8 GB and upgrade later on as needed, but ram is cheap for now.